# The result of CSS styles is not what I expect

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-specificity

I have the following html that is using Bootstrap stylesheets: `<button class="label btn-lg">Save</button>` My understanding of [CSS Specificity rules](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) that btn-lg overrides label values (*When selectors have an equal specificity value, the latest rule is the one that counts*). However, regardless which order I use for classes, label supersedes btn-lg

How do I make btn-lg override label?

Comment: Without seeing your CSS this is going to be a tough nut to crack. Also its not the order the classes are applied to the element, its the order they come in the stylesheet that will impact the specificity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"When selectors have an equal specificity value, the latest rule is the one that counts"
This means that lowest CSS rule in your stylesheet will be applied. So in your case, the .label class appears after .btn-lg in the bootstrap stylesheet.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Given that both classes are in stock Bootstrap file, I take it there is no way to make .label class prevail (obviously, without creating my class, or creating span within, or something equally kludgy). Right?

Answer (score 1):

"Latest rule" means last rule in CSS file, not in class order.

Links to rules at the same file:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L3491 
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L4897

Comment: I wish I could accept this reply as well - two very similar and equally correct answers came a few minutes apart ;)